# Error from Tasks job when referencing a model that uses from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, pythonanywhere

My blog.models is using:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

That model is being called from my script which I run as a task every hour. Here's the error that I'm seeing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/redinv/src/cron.py", line 8, in <module>
    from blog.models import ImagePost, MyPost, ScheduledPost
  File "/home/redinv/src/blog/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 103, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 134, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 60, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

2020-06-25 00:50:25 -- Completed task, took 3.95 seconds, return code was 1.
```

In my settings file under INSTALLED_APPS =, I already have:

```
'django.contrib.auth',
```

This code is of course working locally on my machine and I'm trying to figure what's the issue here?

I tried running that script from two locations to see if there was an issue trying to find the import files:

```
/home/username/src
/home/username/src/blog
```

Same result for both.

Any assistance is appreciate it, I'm pretty new at python.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Django code from outside the context of a website, you need to initialize Django first.  There are two ways to do that:

- Run the `setup` function to set things up; [this part of the Django docs explains how to do that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage)
- Change the code that you want to run in your task into a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/).  This is a little more work, but I would recommend it as a better option in the long term.